# Is Visual Studio Test Manager(MTM) tool for a developer?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I wanted to know if Visual Studio Test Manager(MTM) tool is for developers' assistance only or a QA engineer can use it too? According to my knowledge, it connects with Team Project in TFS(Team foundation server) where the test cases could be executed which means it is for developers. Please anyone confirm if I am right or wrong?

Comment: Why does the fact that it integrates with TFS mean it's for developers? What's wrong with QA engineers, project managers, or other stakeholders using TFS?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) is a tool designed for testers to manage their test cases. It provides tool for testers to create, manage, and record the results of tests.

In addition it can use built I data collectors to pull data from systems under test to create actionable bugs. It can record and manage exploratory testing sessions and automatically associated bugs, test cases, and requirements. If you use the automated build and deploy services you can record your test results against a specific build (complied version) of your product. With test impact analysis you can have MTM identify which manual tests are impacted by code changes so that you can minimize your test matrix and speed time to delivery.

All of this data, and its relationships, are also loaded into a data warehouse and cube which can be used to report on any aspect of testing and its execution results.

All this data is stored within Team Foundation Server as part of Microsoft's cross-platform, multi-discipline Application Lifecycle Management tools.